# How can I de-reference a 2d array of ints?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
  int (*p)[2][2];
} S;

int main()
{
  int aa[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
  S s = { .p = &aa };
  printf("Four: %p\n", s.p[1][1]);
  return 0;
}
```

I'm expecting a '4' to be printed but I'm getting a memory location instead.

Comment: Are you *sure* you don't want `p` to simply be `int(*p)[2]`, and the ensuing initializer to just set `aa` ? Obviously `%p` is the wrong format specifier for `int`, so no clue what you're doing there.

Comment: Your s.p is not a 2d array but a pointer to one. You need one more level of indirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` is a **pointer to an array**  in the `int (*p)[2][2];` Its not a `2D array` as you tried to print.

Replace

```
printf("Four: %p\n", s.p[1][1]);/** %p is format specifier to prints the address, Instead use %d to print value **/
```

with

```
printf("Four: %d\n", (*s.p)[1][1]);
```

Answer (score 4):

You dereference it like any other pointer, with the unary `*` operator.

However you have to note that [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) will play a role here, since the array subscripting operator has higher precedence than the dereference operator. Therefore you have to do e.g.

```
(*s.p)[x][y]
```

Furthermore you use the wrong format to print an integer. The `"%p"` format is to print an actual pointer, not an integer. Use `"%d"`.

---

As an alternative, remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element. That means for your array `aa`, using it just like that will decay to `&aa[0]`, which is of type `int (*)[2]`. That means you could make your variable the same type, and use plain `aa` in the initialization, and use it like a normal "2d" array:

```
typedef struct
{
  int (*p)[2];
} S;

int main()
{
  int aa[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
  S s = { .p = aa };  // Note: Not using the address-of operator here
  printf("Four: %d\n", s.p[1][1]);  // Using array-indexing works as expected here
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I try that I get a '0', still not getting a '4'.

Comment: @gdonald That's weird, works fine for me. Did you remember to change the `printf` format specifier?

Answer (score 0):

s is a structure containing a pointer to a 2 dimensional array. So with "s.p" you get the pointer to your 2 dimensional array. Considering that:

```
(*(s.p))[1][1]
```

will do the work for you.

I guess you did not intend to use the %p placeholder as it is used to print addresses.